# How to retrieve data from different tables using store procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi guys i have some four tables three tables have primary key and the fourth table has all three foriegn keys..now i want to write a select procedure

```
my tables look like this

          usertable                                       RoleTable
  -----------------------                        ---------------------------
   UserID|UserName|userEmail|Pwd|RoleID                RoleID|RoleName
     1   |Anil    |akanil@gma|123|1                       1   |Admin


       Projecttable                                    WorkAssignedTable
-----------------------                       ---------------------------
ProjectID|ProName|                                  WorkID|userId|ProjectID|RoleID
     1   |Anil                                            |
```

now i want to write a select store procedure for workassigned table where i have to get
[UserName],[UserMailId] from sertbale,[rolename] from role tbale,[ProjectName] from Projecttable can any one help in how to write a store Procedure for this

Comment: @ic...I dnt Know how to use a join,thats  the reason for posting a question here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
    select  WorkAssigned.WorkID, usertable.EmployeeName, usertable.EmployeeEmailId,RoleTable.EmplopyeeRole,Projects.projectName,WorkAssigned.[Status] from WorkAssigned  
inner join EmployeeGroup  on RoleTable.GroupId=WorkAssigned.GroupId
inner join Projects  on Projects.ProjectId=WorkAssigned.ProjectId 
inner join EmployeeDetails on  usertable.EmployeId=WorkAssigned.EmployeId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
    Select U.UserName, R.RoleName,P.ProName from WorkAssignedTable WA 
inner join usertable U on WA.UserID = U.UserID
inner join RoleTable R on WA.RoleID = R.RoleID
inner join Projecttable P on WA.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
```

You can use left outer join (if wanting the whole record of the WorkAssignedTable)